# How can I place both text and graphics on a single page

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to develop some "flash cards" that contain some text in the left third or so of the page and a mindmap or tree graph on the right two thirds of the page.
The text sets up the problem and the graphic diagrams the solution (as a learning aid for accounting concepts).

Is there a good way to get LaTeX to do this? I know that usually LaTeX places text and graphics according to its own rules, but I need this consistent format.

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: if your "flash cards" is only one page large, than you can use two `minipages` or one two column `tabular(x)` environments. Something like `\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\linewidth} ....\end{minipage}\begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth} ... \end{mnipage}` and in the first you pt your text, and in the second images.. If bot are not have the same height, than probably you like to have them vertical centered. In this case just remove option `[t]` ...

Comment: Re "usually LaTeX places text and graphics according to its own rules". No, not really. It only does that *if the user tells it to*. I.e., if the user places his/hers graphic in a `figure` environment, then the user is telling LaTeX "it is OK for you to move this around, if that gives better page breaks". But you don't have to use the `figure` environment, you only use that in contexts where the floating behaviour is desirable, which it is not, in your case.

Answer (score 1):

You cpuld use `tcolorbox` to define a new environment `flashcard` where to write the problem description and figure side by side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{flashcard}[2][]{%
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=#2, 
    sidebyside,
    sidebyside align=top seam,
    bicolor, 
    righthand width=.66\linewidth,
    #1
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{flashcard}{First problem} 
This is nice problem to solve.
\tcblower
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{frog}
\end{flashcard}

\begin{flashcard}[colbacklower=green!30]{Second problem} 
This is another nice problem to solve.
\tcblower
\begin{tikzpicture}
\filldraw[fill=red!30] (0,0)--(2,0)--(1,1)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{flashcard}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one, simple, possible solution (as extension of my comment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{lipsum}
```

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.62\linewidth}
\lipsum*[1]
    \[
c=\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
    \]
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}\hfill\begin{minipage}{0.35\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{}
    \vspace{3em}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \captionof{figure}{}
                    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```